# InferAvroSchema Avro Record Name based on flow attribute

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a common process group that will infer avro schema based on the file i supplied.  But I want to set the Avro Record Name to a name corresponding to the filename i am supplying.  So I used ${filename}.  But the InferAvroSchema got error saying the record name is empty.  Note that before this, I already set the property "filename" to the flowfile attribute and it has a value since i tested it using ReplaceText to see if there's value for ${filename}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this looks like a bug in InferAvroSchema. Many of the properties support expression language, but then the processor doesn't evaluate them against the incoming flow file. So it ends up only being able to use a value typed directly into the property (non-EL), or a value from system or environment properties which doesn't really make sense for a lot of these properties.

I created this JIRA for the issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-2465

The fix is that all of the calls to evaluateAttributeExpressions() should be passing in a flow file like:

```
context.getProperty(CSV_HEADER_DEFINITION).evaluateAttributeExpressions(inputFlowFile).getValue()
```